# How to get Active Admin to work with Pundit after login

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, activeadmin, pundit

I've added the configuration pundit addapter authorization to my application

```
config.authorization_adapter = ActiveAdmin::PunditAdapter
```

When I login with the admin@example.com credentials I'm getting this error.

```
Pundit::NotDefinedError in Admin::Dashboard#index
unable to find policy AdminUserPolicy

Extracted source (around line #2):

insert_tag active_admin_application.view_factory["page"]
```

so I created these files in my policies/active_admin folder

adminuser_policy.rb

```
module ActiveAdmin
class AdminUserPolicy < ApplicationPolicy
class Scope < Struct.new(:user, :scope)
  def resolve
    scope
  end
end
def home?
true
end

def index?
true 
end
def show?
true 
end
def new?
true
end

def create?
 true
end

def update?
true 
end

  def destroy?
    true 
 end
end
```

end

page_policy.rb

```
module ActiveAdmin
class PagePolicy < ApplicationPolicy
  class Scope < Struct.new(:user, :scope)
  def resolve
    scope
  end
 end
   def index?
      true
   end

   def show?
     true
   end
  end
end
```

What am I missing? Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found the answer!

After adding these two lines to the active admin initializer file

```
config.authorization_adapter = ActiveAdmin::PunditAdapter 

#this line sets the default policy to application_policy.rb
config.pundit_default_policy = "ApplicationPolicy"
```

I had to add this to dashboard.rb under app/admin/dashboard.rb

```
def index
  authorize :dashboards, :index?
end
```

Then I created a file in my policies folder called dashboard_policy.rb and added this code

```
class DashboardPolicy < ApplicationPolicy
   def dashboard?
   true
  end
  def index?
   true
  end
 end
```

That got it working!

Comment: Yeah the code you pasted above is simply broken. Specifically please give the full contents of your app/admin/dashboard.rb file.

Answer (score 1):

All I had to do was follow the [documentation](https://activeadmin.info/13-authorization-adapter.html):

`config/initializers/active_admin.rb`

```rb
ActiveAdmin.setup do |config|
  # ...
  config.authorization_adapter = ActiveAdmin::PunditAdapter
  # ...
end
```

`app/policies/active_admin/page_policy.rb` (note the `active_admin` folder!)

```rb
module ActiveAdmin
  class PagePolicy < ApplicationPolicy
    def show?
      case record.name
      when 'Dashboard'
        true
      else
        false
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: I like this answer, it's less code and configuration than the accepted answer. Closer to "convention over configuration" philosophy.