# Can you disable Pundit with Devise and Active Admin?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, activeadmin, pundit

I have an existing Rails app that has Devise / Pundit running on the User model.

I have followed:

[How to get Active Admin to work with Pundit after login](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27883386/how-to-get-active-admin-to-work-with-pundit-after-login)

https://gist.github.com/tomchentw/8579571

I don't need authorization right now - Devise for authentication will do.  Can I just `"turn off"` Pundit for Active Admin?

**UPDATE**

This is super monkey patch:

```
after_action :verify_policy_scoped, only: [:index] if controller_path.split('/').first == "admin"
```

It works but I don't think it's ideal.

Answer (score 0):

```
config.authentication_method = false  
config.current_user_method   = false
```

In your config/initializers/active_admin.rb

Comment: That disables authentication - I wanted to disable authorization.  I am saying if the AdminUser is logged in they are authorized by default.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to set up authorization adapter

Setting up your own AuthorizationAdapter is easy! The following example shows how to set up and tie your authorization adapter class to Active Admin:

```
# app/models/only_authors_authorization.rb
class NotAdminAuthorization < ActiveAdmin::AuthorizationAdapter

  def authorized?(action, subject = nil)
   false
  end

end
```

then

```
config.authorization_adapter = "NotAdminAuthorization"
```

and other you can define the namespace toggle

```
ActiveAdmin.setup do |config|
  config.namespace :admin do |ns|
    ns.authorization_adapter = "NotAdminAuthorization"
  end
  config.namespace :my_user do |ns|
    ns.authorization_adapter =  ActiveAdmin::PunditAdapter
  end
end
```

Then like this to

```
ActiveAdmin.register Post, namespace: :my_user
```

Comment: That does not work - I still get endless Pundit PolicyScoping and Authorization errors

Comment: did you define namespace ? use authorization_adapter =  ActiveAdmin::PunditAdapter for other user

Comment: I am confused as to what this toggle does.  Now I have config.authorization_adapter = ActiveAdmin::PunditAdapter set.  Every page I go to in AA results in: ```Pundit::NotDefinedError at /admin/dashboard
unable to find policy `AdminUserPolicy` for `#<AdminUser id: nil, email: "", encrypted_password: "", reset_password_token: nil, reset_password_sent_at: nil, remember_created_at: nil, sign_in_count: 0, current_sign_in_at: nil, last_sign_in_at: nil, current_sign_in_ip: nil, last_sign_in_ip: nil>````

Answer (score 0):

In case someone is having this issue. This is another solution:

*app/controllers/application_controller.rb*

```
after_action :verify_authorized, except: %i[index], unless: :active_admin_controller?

after_action :verify_authorized, only: %i[index], unless: :active_admin_controller?

protected

def active_admin_controller?
  is_a?(ActiveAdmin::BaseController)
end
```

This disables Pundit's authorization checks on all Active Admin controllers.